# I2C Read function gets stuck after sending Acknowledge bit

Tags: c, pic, i2c

I'm trying to communicate with a MPU-9250 (Accelerometer and a lot of other stuff) from my PIC16F1789. My functions look like the following:

```
void i2cWait(){
  while((SSP1STAT & 0x04) || (SSP1CON2 & 0x1F));
}

unsigned char i2cReadCycle(unsigned char regAddr){
    unsigned char val;
    // Start
    i2cWait();
    SEN = 1;

    // Address + Write Bit
    i2cWait();
    SSPBUF = (slvAdd<<1 | (0b1<<0)); // address slave + write
    i2cWait();

    //Register address
    SSP1BUF = regAddr; // address register + read
    i2cWait();

    //Start
    SEN = 1;
    i2cWait();

    // Address + Read Bit
    SSP1BUF = ((slvAdd<<1) | (0b0<<0)); //Address + read (0)
    i2cWait();

    // Daten Auslesen
    RCEN = 1;
    i2cWait();
    val = SSP1BUF;
    i2cWait();
    ACKDT = 1; // set acknowledge Bit (1 = Not Acknowledge, 0 = Acknowledge)
    ACKEN = 1; // send acknowledge Bit

    // Stop
    i2cWait();
    PEN = 1;

    return val;
}
```

I've worked with the "Single-Byte Read Sequence" on page 35 of the 9250 Datasheet:
https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/5/5/0/MPU9250REV1.0.pdf

And the PIC Datasheet:
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001675C.pdf

When debugging, the program gets stuck in the i2cWait() after I send the NACK Bit.
It gets stuck because the ACKEN Bit (Bit 4) of the SSPCON2 register (Page 341 of PIC datasheet) doesn't get cleared, so the program gets stuck in the while().

Why doesnt the Bit get cleared by hardware?

Comment: I didn't review the complete I2C datasheet, but is the `ACK` bit cleared by the clock cycles? If so, then in debug, you can miss it. I would make sure that your debug mode doesn't break prior to the `i2cWait()` or in it.

Comment: @daShier What do you mean by is it cleared by clock cycles?

Comment: @vhrerah Do the bits in `SSP1STAT` and/or `SSP1CON2` remain set until you acknowledge them, or are they set just for the single clock cycle (in which case, it's possible to miss them when setting breakpoints)? Also keep in mind that, depending on your debugger hardware, you might only have software breakpoints in the PIC, which can be a real pain when debugging hardware timing.

Comment: @daShier Does the slave have to pull the signal down? Because if so, it could be a problem with the slave device

Comment: can you also post your i2c initialization code?

Comment: after the first write and before the first read there should be a "Restart" , use RSEN = 1 instead of SEN = 1. I know the datasheet doesn't show this but this is the specification of the I2C bus. https://www.i2c-bus.org/repeated-start-condition/

Comment: @pm101 Thank you very much, this solved my Problem! I really didn't see that in the datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using 0b1<<0 for "writing" together with the slave address. However, according to the datasheet of MPU9250REV1.0, it should be 0. Check section 7.4 on page 35.

Although it might be counter-intuitive to set '0' for writes, it makes sense if you think of the "General Call" that ist initiated with the slave address  0b0000000 and the "write" bit 0.

This also means to change the "read" bit in your code to 1.

In the current implementation, mixing up read and write bits, leads to the issue being stuck waiting after setting the NACK.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sadly, even after changing the values, the program is still stuck in the i2cWait function. Do you have any other Idea why that could be the case?

Comment: Are you receiving the data correctly? Reading the data sheet on page 35, it says "The NACK condition is defined such that the SDA line remains high at the 9th clock cycle." So I don't think you actually require the last i2cWait() call at all.
Antoher typical cause for i2c not working are the missing pull-up resistors on the SCL and SDA line. In section 7.2 you find this sentence: " SDA and SCL lines typically need pull-up resistors to VDD."